# 404 error after URL REWRITE in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

By URL REWRITE Management i changed

```
url = www.domain.com/seller/profile/detail/mobile-shop
```

to

```
www.domain.com/mobile-shop
```

But now getting 404 error . What can be the problem.

**id path** :-  mobile-shop

**Request path** :- seller/profile/detail/mobile-shop

**Target path** :- mobile-shop

Comment: did you reindex?

Comment: yes i reindex ( catalog url rewrite).                                                                      Will my new url call the detail action of profile controller?

Comment: I just want to use the same action(detail) in different url(www.domain.com/mobile-shop).

Answer (score 1):

Please make changes as per below. (
URL Rewrite Information)

**Type:** Custom

**Store:** Select store which you want to do this change. (Make sure you need to add this in each of store.)

**ID Path:** mobile-shop

**Request Path:** mobile-shop

**Target Path:** seller/profile/detail/mobile-shop

**Redirect:** No

Comment: 1)This thing was not not redirecting at all. It was opening www.domain.com/seller/profile/detail/mobile-shop                                                                                             2)I did the same thing with **Redirect**  301 and was being redirected to www.domain.com/mobile-shop with 404 error.